# AWS sam cli: maven failed to return a version string with helloworld tutorial

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I recently started to get an error with maven when running the command `sam build`.

I decided to create the hello world application (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-getting-started-hello-world.html) to see if I would also get the same error and I get it.

Here is the output after running `sam build`:

```
Building codeuri: [service] runtime: java11 metadata: {} functions: ['service']
C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.CMD failed to return a version string using the '-v' option. The workflow is unable to check that the version of the JVM used is compatible with AWS Lambda.
```

Here is the output of `C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\mvn.CMD -v`:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_261, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\jre
Default locale: en_CA, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: I think you might need to install jdk 11.  Seems you have jdk8. (I could be wrong)

Comment: I changed to java 11 and still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

There is text "The system cannot find the path specified." as an output of "mvn.CMD -v" which is not ok.

The way it worked for me is added "set JAVA_HOME=<JAVA_PATH8_JDK>"
eg. `set JAVA_HOME=C:\md\sw\java\in` in mvn.cmd

If you are working on visual code you have to restart visual studio code after maven setup .